# How do I set up an inferred type list getter and setter?

Tags: java, list, generics, types, inference

```
List<T> objectList = null;
public <T> List<T> getObjectList() { return this.objectList; }
public <T> void setObjectList(List<T> objList) { this.objectList = objList; }
```

The problem appears to be the field declaration. Semantically, I am wondering why, since the goal is to infer the type, this doesn't work.

From a short term gain point of view, I just want something that works.

Icing on the cake would be if someone would point me to a detailed, i.e. in-depth, discussion of inferred types with examples.

The context is a raw string returned from a request-reply bus message that needs to be de-serialized into a list of like javabean objects. I realize I could just create a marker interface and make all of my javabeans impl it, however, that seems like kind of a wanky solution to me.

JDK 1.6 (no chance of moving up to 7 or 8)

Comment: `List<?> objectList = null;` and then a cast in the method body seems to be the quick and dirty way to get this going.

Comment: `List<T> objectList;` Where is this declared? Where is `T` declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typed your methods... don't - remove `<T>` from the get/set methods:

```
public List<T> getObjectList() { return this.objectList; }
public void setObjectList(List<T> objList) { this.objectList = objList; }
```

When you code

```
public <T> List<T> getObjectList() { return this.objectList; }
public <T> void setObjectList(List<T> objList) { this.objectList = objList; }
```

The initial `<T>` declares a type *for the scope of the method call*, and you have used the same name for the generic parameter as your class, so the method type *hides* the class type.

Had you coded:

```
public <X> List<T> getObjectList() { return this.objectList; }
public <X> void setObjectList(List<T> objList) { this.objectList = objList; }
```

It would have worked too. Of course the `X` generic parameter would have been ignored, but at least it would have been obvious that it was unnecessary.